# How can i create a graph/tree programmatically to generate test data

Tags: python, algorithm, tree, data-science

I have a need for generating data for performance testing for an application which has data with lot of relations between entities. Here is example.

```
DivA                                     
DivA[Payroll,HR,IT] 
Payroll[Location,Classification,files]
HR[Location,Training,Compliance]
IT[Clearance,Experience,Compliance]
Location[City,Country]
Classification[ExemptionType,Expiry date]
....
```

From above "schema"

I need to generate data using following algorithm

1. Create parent entity (Ex: Consumer Electronics Division )
2. Populate all children (Ex: Consumer Electronics Division [Payroll,HR,IT] )
3. Check if children has more children (Ex: Consumer Electronics Division [Payroll[Location,Classification,files],HR [Location,Training,Compliance],IT[Clearance,Experience,Compliance]]
   ....
   keep going until you don't find any more children.

Is there any algorithm/Data structure that helps to create data like this easily?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

### [Diagram](https://mermaid.ink/img/pako:eNqNkU2KwzAMha8StE4vkMXAMA1MoYuhzW7chUiUVmDLxrFLTendx_kpJLvxxnqP7wkhPaG1HUEFV4_uVhxPSvZ8_yz-8xZ0t_sofjB5q_VUf5_G79AoWbtH22JgK5P40jgM3PPK6lnToGQOb-jGIwvLdU5a4zSjtKTk0CzNCP3oTKp-OPJMb7nmtyNwSAsRJfikZDvUb_0g48aqSY7K3JZ9KjoMdIESDHmD3OW9PZXkTUC4kSEFVS476jHqoEDJK6PRjaG642A9VMFHKgFjsOck7VvPzJ4xX8FA1aMe6PUHchuClQ)

You can find many graph algorithms, but if you want to do conceptual research on the subject, you can be free to choose and develop the terminology and algorithms.

In terms of answer or idea, I would like to point the graph above.

The direction of the arrows, whether they turn backwards, and many other details will determine the graph algorithm.

If you can picture the subject in a drawing -not have to be literally- with the goal you want to achieve, it may be possible to improve the answer.

PS. Lac of rep. prevents me from posting the image.I can only link the graph